# Mongoose populate from external results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Given that I have 2 completely different server and database.

```
Server A, Database A:
Database A's model as ModelA :{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    fieldA: any
}

Server B, Database B:
Database B's model as ModelB :{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    fieldB: any
}

Database A _id === Database B _id

Expected result:[
    { _id, fieldA, fieldB }
    ...
]
```

Scenario:
From ***Server A***, by fetching an api from ***Server B*** I got a list of ***ModelB***'s result. I would want to populate ***ModelA*** by using the fetch result.

Let's say
***ModelA***'s find() result = ***resultA***
***ModelB***'s find() result = ***resultB***

My solution so far:

Solution A:
Flow: Fetch from ***Server B*** => Extract list of _id by using map => ***ModelA***.find(listOfExtractedIds) => compare and merge result by nested loop ***resultA*** on ***resultB***
*This is extremely inefficient as multiple loop is involved.

Solution B:
Flow Fetch from ***Server B*** => ***ModelA***.populate(***resultB***, {path:"_id"})
* This is my ideal solution, but it does not work because ***Server A*** has no access to ***Model B*** and there's no ***ref*** involved.

Is there a better approach to this problem? Or is there a way for ***Solution B*** to work as expected?

*PS ***Server A*** has no access to ***ModelB*** which is on ***Server B***.
*No ***ref*** specified on both model.

Answer (score 0):

Well Solution A is the only solution in that situation, because apparantly two different databases cannot join data.

The only thing you could do is optimize the Solution A to improve performance, e.g. using some kind of a cache.